# Error pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on my machine, I tried to install a new version of libc6 which I downloaded from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libc6) I made that because a new version of libcv depends on it, I thought after installing libcv dependency it will be installed! Here is my `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` file now http://pastebin.com/7YdwKyvr

**This error is preventing me from upgrading to saucy, so I need a way to fix it.**

Comment: Err... libc6 is the holy mary of dependencies. I wouldn't even try to upgrade it without using `apt-get`. BTW, where is the apt.log?

Comment: sorry, edited the question.

Comment: what an elaborate error report!

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, `libc6` is the holy mary of dependencies. With more than 15k reverse dependencies<sup>1</sup> I would not try to replace the one I have installed with some other, less mixing saucy with precise packages. If you really want the latest libcv, you have two (three) options:

1. Upgrade to sacuy (or install saucy in a Virtual Machine)
2. Backport the library. Note that some build dependencies [required by the package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/saucy/opencv) are not included in precise, so they should be backported too.

Note 1: you can find out using `apt-cache rdepends libc6 | wc -l`

Comment: This error is preventing me from upgrading to saucy, which is the main intention of my question, can you please guide me how to successfully upgrading?

Comment: you shouldn't skip upgrades. You must upgrade to quantal, then raring and then to saucy. http://askubuntu.com/q/34430/169736

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my package manager which displaying that their is an upgrade option for 12.10 http://imagebin.org/281861

Comment: @Wazery I would report a bug in that case, as it says in the image. That shouldn't happen.